# What is the classification of conjunctions and connectors?

Tags: grammar

I learned that the "transition and connectors" are not the same as the conjunctions, as far as I know, the conjunctions are divided into two major types, coordinators and subordinators, but then there are other kinds of linking words, "transitions and connectors" which can be showing; connectors (connection, result), contrast, emphasis, addition, time showing chronology, time, comment.

I got that from [here](http://kmckean.myteachersite.com/teacher/files/documents/transitions.pdf) and I can't make sense of it because, in the Cambridge dictionary, they say that [conjunctions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conjunctions) are linking words, but I understand linking words like transition and connector words, are all the "transition and connectors" subordinators conjunctions?

I'm not making a clear question, I'm asking if someone can explain the difference and classification of these words; linking words, conjunctions, connectors and transition words, coordinators and subordinators conjunctions.

Answer (score -1):

I researched in a book and I found that the Conjunctions are the root, that is, the linking words or connectors are part of the conjunctions, and the subordinating conjunctions can be divided into the kind of usage, please if you know I'm wrong, let me know
[image]